# Нейронная сеть для оценки недвижимости на дипломную работу

Tags: нейронные-сети

В универе пришла пора выбора темы дипломной работы. Куратор дал тему Моделирование нейронной сети для оценки рыночной стоимости недвижимости. Причем ситуация такая, что в работе с нейронными сетями опыта ноль, в принципе времени у меня достаточно, чтобы научиться. Но вопрос не в этом, хотел бы узнать вашего мнения по поводу сложности проекта, является ли подобная система уровнем дипломного проекта, ведь оценка рыночной стоимости недвижимости это довольно сложный процесс, не хотелось бы себя "закопать" дипломным проектом.

Comment: Во многом ваш проект будет зависеть от качества данных на которых вы будете обучать и тестировать вашу НС. У вас есть доступ к таким данным? Если речь идет о данных в свободном доступе (например Boston Housing), то в сети можно найти решения неплохо справляющиеся с этим набором данных.

Comment: Да будет написан парсер, который соберет данные с открытого доступа.

Comment: Меня очень интересует эта тема и есть немалый опыт в недвижке. Если захочешь серьезный проект делать можем пообщаться в личке. Сложность проекта от ноль целых хрен десятых - если просто спарсить доску и посчитать среднюю цену, до очень сложной при толковых подходах с результатами близкими к реальным.

Comment: На досках хотелки продавцов, реальные продажи например в росреестре, или на аукционах (-10-15%?). Да, я интересуюсь только российской недвижимостью и говорю сейчас про этот рынок.

Answer (score -1):

"Оценка рыночной стоимости недвижимости с помощью нейронной сети" настолько избитая и тысячу раз описанная - в том числе и в интернет - тема, с готовыми решениями, анализом и пр., что с моей точки зрения это тема ниже необходимого уровня магистрской дипломной работы.  Правда не знаю, что вы будете говорить при этом про новизну,значимость или даже важность темы. Ну, разве что - бакалаврской, и то, с натяжкой.

Comment: Ну а есть решения которые таки более-менее реальные результаты дают? Я давно в этой теме, но с реальными результатами не сталкивался. Все что видел "средняя температура по больнице"

Comment: Да сколько угодно. Вот из самого последнего https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-data-science-project-from-scratch-dc4f096a62a1 с детальным "разбором полетов"